# C# saved folder downloaded from Google drive cannot access in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, google-drive-api

After I finished my practical class in school, I will upload the whole saved folder to google drive for me to revise at home. However, when I re-download the whole file from google drive at home, I couldn't open it on visual studio 2013, the whole file is just become different.

This is when you saved it in computer 
[image]

This is after you re-download from google drive
[image]

Is there any ways I can open back my work?

Comment: It seems `.sln` files on your computer are associated with notepad(?). Just open the .sln solution file from inside Visual Studio instead.

Comment: the file type .sln is changed after upload to google drive.

Comment: Well, then it would seem to be a google drive problem, not a programming tool related problem. Try zipping the files up and transfer the zip file instead.

Comment: it works! i will aware of this next time. Thank you and have a pleasant day.

Answer (score 0):

What errors do you get? Does it just open in notepad?

Try right click -> open with...

Find visual studio and select it. Or, open visual studio and File -> Open -> your solution file.

If that doesn't fix it you may have to give us more than that. An error, a behavior... Something to work with.

Comment: i found that when the file is saved locally in the computer, it saved as a visual studio solution file .sln, but after i uploaded to google drive, it automatically convert to text document.
For example, in computer it saved as windowapplication1 and the file type is visual studio solution (.sln)
But after i uploaded to google drive, it become windowapplication1.sln and the file type is text document